# improve draw background performance

Tags: android

I'm drawing a background (a grid) in a View, basically all the screen filled with triangles (note I need to draw the triangles), but it seems to get the application slower.

Is there any configurations I can do in order to optimize the application performance?, for example; some configurations to draw my background with less quality.

thanks

Comment: Your triangles are changing constantly?

Comment: Yes, I need to draw them constantly. I need to implement a zoom in and out effect.

Comment: @forumercio did you find a solution to this problem? I'm also having a similar issue. It would be ideal that the background was only drawn once. Thanks.

Comment: @forumercio finally I found a solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error the solution I found was doing the custom drawing on the [OnSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) event of a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) instead of [OnDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) so that the code is only exectued once. In the *OnSizeChanged* event I draw the background in a temporary canvas, set it into a bitmap, created a [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) for it and call [setBackgroundDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) with the *BitmapDrawable*. After that I do the custom drawing and paint it into a bitmap to which is set to a custom [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) which can be zoomed and scrolled while performance is not affected. Custom *ImageView* is similar to the example I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792331/sluggish-zoom-and-scroll-with-gridview-in-android).